# Why did Fitz take Shrewd's knife?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings

In the *Farseer Trilogy*'s first part, *The Assassin's Apprentice*, while he is trained by Chade, Fitz receives the order to steal something irrelevant in King Shrew's room. He refuses, to prove his loyalty, but a few days later, when he is invited to Shrew's room, he steals a knife in front of the King.

The Kings knows it but he does not react. Later, Fitz stabs the knife in Chade's workshop as an evidence to his accomplished mission.

Did he notice that Shrewd saw him taking the knife? Does he want to fool Chade, making him believe he finally decided to accomplished the mission? His intentions are not clear to me.

Comment: It’s been a while since I read it, but perhaps he was trying to prove that he could be loyal to the king *and* fulfill the letter of Chade’s order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...while he is trained by Chade, Fitz receives the order to steal something irrelevant in King Shrew's room. He refuses, to prove his loyalty, but a few days later, when he is
>   invited to Shrew's room, he steals a knife in front of the King.

To be clear, **after** King Shrewd apologized to FitzChivalry for testing him with a conflict between his oath to the King and his obedience to Chade, Fitz's mentor, **then** Fitz **openly** steals the knife while the King watches.  By "stealing" the knife openly, with the King watching, Fitz satisfied the requirement to steal from the King without violating his oath of loyalty to the King.

> The Kings knows it but he does not react. Later, Fitz stabs the knife
>   in Chade's workshop as an evidence to his accomplished mission.

<strike>I do not have the books in front of me</strike> Assassin's Apprentice is actually $1.99 for Kindle edition on Amazon right now :)

Shrewd did react in a minor way, enough to make it clear that he was fully aware of what Fitz was doing:

```
[Shrewd] made a motion that dismissed me.  And I rose,
but as I did so I took from his tray a little silver knife,
all engraved, that he had been using to cut fruit with.
I looked him in the eyes as I did so, and quite openly 
slipped it up my sleeve.  King Shrewd's eyes widened, 
but he said not a word.
```

> Did he notice that Shrewd saw him taking the knife?

Yes, Fitz took the knife in an obvious manner, and saw Shrewd's reaction.  They both knew that they both knew.

> Does he want to
>   fool Chade, making him believe he finally decided to accomplished the
>   mission? His intentions are not clear to me.

When Fitz drove the knife into the mantel over Chade's fireplace, the message he was sending was simple - *"I completed your task.  I did it in my own way, without compromising my oath to my King.  Do not test my loyalty to King Shrewd, or to you, again."*

Answer (score 1):

Chade starts testing Fitz ability to follow orders that can be mean (after all, Fitz is supposed to be an assassin) by asking him to do "a few mischiefs" and steal some small items from people in the castle. But when he asks to steal from the king, its a different kind of test - it is supposed to check, is Fitz just a ruthless person following orders or does he have a loyalty to Shrew.

Fitz does steal a fruit knife from king , but he does it in such way that Shrew knows what Fitz is doing - he picks up the knife while looking king in the eye - it is to say "I have to follow Chade's order but I won't do it against your will and you can stop me any time you want, because I don't want to break my oath to you which is more important that tasks given by my tutor".

He later stabs the knife into mantel over the fireplace (where it stays forever) just to say  "Do not test my loyalty again".